# Use object names within a list in lapply/ldply

Tags: r, plyr

In attempting to answer [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213779/how-to-have-multiple-color-scales-into-one-plot-r/15214213#15214213) earlier, I ran into a problem that seemed like it should be simple, but I couldn't figure out.

If I have a list of dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1:3, x=rnorm(3))
df2 <- data.frame(a=1:3, x=rnorm(3))
df3 <- data.frame(a=1:3, x=rnorm(3))

df.list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

That I want to `rbind` together, I can do the following:

```
df.all <- ldply(df.list, rbind)
```

However, I want another column that identifies which `data.frame` each row came from. I expected to be able to use the `deparse(substitute(x))` method ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520772/in-r-how-to-get-an-objects-name-from-the-object-itself) and elsewhere) to get the name of the relevant `data.frame` and add a column. This is how I approached it:

```
fun <- function(x) {
  name <- deparse(substitute(x))
  x$id <- name
  return(x)
}
df.all <- ldply(df.list, fun)
```

Which returns

```
  a          x      id
1 1  1.1138062 X[[1L]]
2 2 -0.5742069 X[[1L]]
3 3  0.7546323 X[[1L]]
4 1  1.8358605 X[[2L]]
5 2  0.9107199 X[[2L]]
6 3  0.8313439 X[[2L]]
7 1  0.5827148 X[[3L]]
8 2 -0.9896495 X[[3L]]
9 3 -0.9451503 X[[3L]]
```

So obviously each element of the list does not contain the name I think it does. Can anyone suggest a way to get what I expected (shown below)?

```
  a          x  id
1 1  1.1138062 df1
2 2 -0.5742069 df1
3 3  0.7546323 df1
4 1  1.8358605 df2
5 2  0.9107199 df2
6 3  0.8313439 df2
7 1  0.5827148 df3
8 2 -0.9896495 df3
9 3 -0.9451503 df3
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but you might be interested in the various methods used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15162197/324364).

Comment: Shooting yourself in the foot by not using a named list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define your list with names and it should give you an `.id` column with the `data.frame` name

```
df.list <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3)
df.all <- ldply(df.list, rbind)
```

Output:

```
  .id a           x
1 df1 1  1.84658809
2 df1 2 -0.01177462
3 df1 3  0.58579469
4 df2 1 -0.64748756
5 df2 2  0.24384614
6 df2 3  0.59012676
7 df3 1 -0.63037679
8 df3 2 -1.17416295
9 df3 3  1.09349618
```

Then you can know the `data.frame` name from the column `df.all$.id`

*Edit:*
As per @Gary Weissman's comment if you want to generate the names automatically you can do

```
names(df.list) <- paste0('df',seq_along(df.list)
```

Comment: I was writing up the same thing except with `do.call(rbind, df.list)` instead of `ldply` which also gives the original row.

Comment: The only disadvantage with this approach is that you actually have to type out the names of all your dataframes by hand.  Could you do something like `names(df.list) <- paste0('df',seq_along(df.list))`

Comment: +1 This is really helpful - in essence the answer to my question is "Make it a named list" - but I appreciate that you went further!

Comment: @Gary Weissman - that is good in that it gives a unique identifier, but doesn't link to the specific name. Of course, once it's an unnamed list, it's not really possible to make that link.

Comment: Glad it worked. Yes the key is "*named list*" and you have the option to provide the name manually or automatically as per @Gary's comment

Answer (score 3):

Using base only, one could try something like:

```
dd <- lapply(seq_along(df.list), function(x) cbind(df_name = paste0('df',x),df.list[[x]]))

do.call(rbind,dd)
```

Comment: Heh. I _did_ try it, but that was before you actually finished editing it. For a while, you had only the `lapply` line up there (and a different version of it too boot) that definitely did not work.

Comment: ah sorry, my browser was freezing and my edits got mangled ;-(

Comment: +1 At least a unique name is given for each element, but the issue is that each is named in order (ie not to do with the dataframe name).

Comment: @alexwhan an alternative to grab the name could be to replace with `df_name = names(df.list)[x]`

Answer (score 2):

In your definition, `df.list` does not have names, however, even then the deparse substitute idiom does not appear to work easilty (as `lapply` calls `.Internal(lapply(X, FUN))` -- you would have to look at the source to see if the object name was available and how to get it

Something like

```
names(df.list) <- paste('df', 1:3, sep = '')

foo <- function(n, .list){
         .list[[n]]$id <- n
         .list[[n]]
       } 

     a          x id
1 1  0.8204213  a
2 2 -0.8881671  a
3 3  1.2880816  a
4 1 -2.2766111  b
5 2  0.3912521  b
6 3 -1.3963381  b
7 1 -1.8057246  c
8 2  0.5862760  c
9 3  0.5605867  c
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use your `function`, instead of `deparse(substitute(x))` use `match.call()`, and you want the second argument, making sure to convert it to `character`

```
 name <- as.character(match.call()[[2]])
```